# Null Dapper.net query still returning Null Reference Exception with FirstOrDefault()

Tags: c#, linq, dapper, nullreferenceexception

I would like to return the max Id from a table using Dapper.net

```
var x = connection.Query<int>("SELECT max(val) FROM info").FirstOrDefault();
```

This works - unless no row exists then I get an

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Shouldn't the 'OrDefault' mean this returns 0 when no records are present?

How can I return 0 - or some non null value to prevent a crash.

thx

Comment: do yo get error in var x = connection.Query<int>("SELECT max(val) FROM info").FirstOrDefault(); or before using x?

Comment: Use ISNULL() with max(val)

Comment: @viveknuna thanks for SQL idea - I would like to understand why this isn't working in c# too.

Comment: That query should only return one value, thus the "OrDefault" is not the issue.  Try changing the type from `int` to `int?`.  Or change the query to not return null in the first place.

Comment: You are trying to cast a `NULL` to an `int`.

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers i get the error on the var x line - yes before using it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Shouldn't the 'ordefault' return 0 if the query is null?

Comment: @niico The Error is occurring before you even get to the `FirstOrDefault` part when Dapper is trying to put a `null` into an `int`.

Comment: @juharr That makes sense - how can I make Dapper not return a null reference exception (without changing the sql)?

Comment: The issue here is that `select max(val) from info`, when `info` contains no values, returns a single `NULL`, whereas `select val from info` would return an empty list. Since there is a possibility of a null response in the query, you'll need to accept a list of `int?`, or change the query.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The issue is that you're telling Dapper to expect a sequence of `int`, but you actually have the possiblity of a `null` value.  So you either need to change the type

```
var x = connection.Query<int?>("SELECT max(val) FROM info").Single() ?? 0;
```

Or you need to change the query to handle the `null`.

```
var x = connection.Query<int>("SELECT COALESCE(max(val), 0) FROM info").Single();
```

I'm using `Single` here because this query should only ever return exactly one row.

You would use `FirstOrDefault` when you expect a sequence and only want the first item, or if there are no items you want the default value of the item type.

Comment: thx so FirstOrDefault doesn't help us in this situation? I have to have another specific null check (assuming I go the first route).

Comment: Yes, the `OrDefault` part only applies to an empty result set (no rows).

Comment: Thanks - I keep forgetting that SQL aggregates can return null, and had incorrectly used 
`SELECT SUM(ISNULL(myCol, 0))` instead of `SELECT ISNULL(SUM(myCol), 0)`

Comment: Note to self: though `Single` is most appropriate for this particular query, you could still use the other variants like `FirstOrDefault`, `First`, etc.  The actual problem is that Dapper never converts nulls returned from the database to values automatically, so it's up to you to handle them manually.

Answer (score 3):

```
var x = connection.Query<int>("SELECT ISNULL(max(val), 0) FROM info").Single();
```

You can use ISNULL if you want to select default value if value is null.